# NullReferenceException from DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.GetLinearPosition()

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a form that displays a chart using Microsoft's `DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` control (I use version 4 of the .NET framework). I also draw some annotations on the chart, and to locate them I need to know about the chart axes.

The code

```
myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(location)
```

gives me a `NullReferenceException`. The chart is definitely instantiated and I can set properties of the `AxisX`-  for instance,  `myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1` works fine.

Drilling into the exception message, it looks like the trouble is in the `GetLinearPosition` method, which is something internal to the `Chart` control:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.GetLinearPosition(Double axisValue)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.GetPosition(Double axisValue)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Axis.ValueToPixelPosition(Double axisValue)
```

Does anyone have any insight to get me started fixing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That rings a bell.  I think the trouble is that this can't work until the control has figured out its data-to-display mapping.  Which doesn't happen until it needs to paint itself, in typical lazy fashion.  Call Update() first, something like that.

Comment: You figured it out, Hans. The chart is on a `TabControl` tab, and I had to bring that tab to front (with the `TabControl.SelectedTab` property) before making the call to `ValueToPixelPosition`. Why don't you write up an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer came in a comment to the question from Hans Passant:

> That rings a bell. I think the trouble is that this can't work until
>   the control has figured out its data-to-display mapping. Which doesn't
>   happen until it needs to paint itself, in typical lazy fashion. Call
>   Update() first, something like that.

Which got me far enough to make this discovery:

> You figured it out, Hans. The chart is on a `TabControl` tab, and I had
>   to bring that tab to front (with the `TabControl.SelectedTab` property)
>   before making the call to `ValueToPixelPosition`.

Comment: Similarly, I had to make the form visible and do an update() to the chart before my error went away.  I was making the form visible after I had created the charts so I switched the order and it worked.

Comment: From where are you calling the update? Are you using which event to trigger this?